# D3 monotone interpolation causing little loops

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm displaying data on a line graph with monotone interpolation. But in some cases little loops appear.

Is there away to fix this while keeping the same look as monotone (so not just using linear) and having the line hit all the points?

JSFiddle showing the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/WkvMx/3/

Code to replicate:

```
var data = 
[
    {date: '2013-08-01', value: 234},   
    {date: '2013-08-02', value: 244},   
    {date: '2013-08-04', value: 1034},   
    {date: '2013-08-06', value: 1004},   
    {date: '2013-08-28', value: 234},   
    {date: '2013-08-29', value: 233}  
]

var width = 500;
var height = 250;

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
   .range([0, width])
   .domain([parse('2013-08-01'), parse('2013-09-01')]);

var max = d3.max(data, function (v) { return v.value; });
var min = d3.min(data, function (v) { return v.value; });

var y = d3.scale.linear()
   .range([height, 0])
   .domain([min, max]).nice(); 

var line = d3.svg.line()
   .interpolate("monotone")
   .x(function(d) { return x(parse(d.date)); })
   .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

var svg = d3.select('body').append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)

svg.append("path")
   .datum(data)
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("d", line)
   .attr("stroke", 'red')

var circlegroup = svg.append("g")

circlegroup.selectAll(".dot")
   .data(data)
   .enter().append("circle")
   .attr("r", 3)
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(parse(d.date)); })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
```

Comment: Hmm, "bundle" with a high tension? http://jsfiddle.net/WkvMx/1/

Comment: Sorry, I should have probably mentioned, the lines need to hit the points as I'll be adding dots. I'll update the question with an updated fiddle.

Comment: Cardinal with high tension? http://jsfiddle.net/WkvMx/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [monotone interpolation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_interpolate) is intended to interpolate monotone datasets, that's it, datasets whose y-coordinate increases, and even in that case, the monotonicity of the interpolation function is not guaranteed, although it can be achieved by modifying the tangents of the curve. The tangents can be controled globally (kind of) using the [`tension`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_tension) method, but it can't be set point by point.

As @Lars pointed out, you can try other interpolation methods better suited for your data, and tweak the tension to get a smooth line that passes by all the input points.

Comment: The `tension()` doesn't do anything for the monotone interpolation.