# D3 radar graph forms loops at connections

Tags: d3.js

This D3 radar chart uses cardinal-closed interpolation. Tiny loops at beginning/end connection points appear (axis 1).

[image]

Anyone know how to resolve this so that they are smooth?

Comment: Have you tried the other interpolations?

Comment: I have. Cardinal doesn't create a smooth "loop" either.

Comment: Have you tied adjusting the tension? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255886/d3-monotone-interpolation-causing-little-loops